# Protect breached email accounts

Tags: authentication, email, multi-factor

We are a big supermarket chain and have had complaints about fraudulent activities from a few customers who have used a particular email domain. We are in the process of implementing MFA on our site. If the customer's email account is already hacked (and username and password on our site) the MFA will not make any difference as the hacker would be able to change/reset the password and update the 2FA mobile number.

Keen to know what would be the best practice advice on tackling such scenarios. We also have a lot of other customers who are using the same email domain as their username/login id on our website.

Comment: I'm not sure it is your responsibility as an unrelated service to protect the email accounts of your customers. I'm not sure how MFA on your service's accounts would help the compromised email accounts of your customers, either. What effect do you want to have? What's your goal?

Comment: The goal is to protect our website incase of a data breach elsewhere. If the email account has been compromised, the attacker could login to our website and update the mobile number on the customer account - by that way making our MFA pointless. (We have a particular email domain that was breached a while ago and we dont know the extent of the breach)

Comment: You can't protect yourself from that. That is far outside your scope of control. And "protect your website"? Don't you mean "protect the user's account"? How is your *site* exposed? If protecting your user's accounts, then you are asking how to protect your users' accounts in the event that an unauthorised person with access to the user's authentication factors. You can't. Adding in tertiary authentication measures is overkill for a supermarket chain and your users will rebel.

Comment: Awesome, yes, I meant "protecting the users account". Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: I would have to agree with @schroeder on many of the points made, but I’m curious to know what kind of customers are we talking about? Is it the consumer, or other businesses as customers. If other businesses, I would say this changes things, and perhaps MFA should be explored. I would also tend to shy away from sms based MFA. Third party services that verify “something you are” vice “something you have” are much easier to deal with IMO